# Removing Data Source Connection Spring + JPA

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

Hy there folks, i'm facing a problem here where I work, there is a project when initialized works with 1 SQL Server Instance, 2 DB2 instances.

The problem is, this project was based on another project to keep the similar structure, but on this new project we don't use the SQL Server instance who is in reference on some xml files, I tried to comment these references, when I start the project on Tomcat, the project show me few errors.

As a new on Spring, how can I remove this connection properly??

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd          
       http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd         
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd         
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="IP_ICMS_RJ" jndi-name="java:comp/env/IP_ICMS_RJ" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="USUARIO_ICMS_RJ" jndi-name="java:comp/env/USUARIO_ICMS_RJ" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="SENHA_ICMS_RJ" jndi-name="java:comp/env/SENHA_ICMS_RJ" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="IP_ICMS_SP" jndi-name="java:comp/env/IP_ICMS_SP" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="USUARIO_ICMS_SP" jndi-name="java:comp/env/USUARIO_ICMS_SP" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="SENHA_ICMS_SP" jndi-name="java:comp/env/SENHA_ICMS_SP" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="PSACWSDocumentURL" jndi-name="java:comp/env/PSACWSDocumentURL" />
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="PSACWSEndPoint" jndi-name="java:comp/env/PSACWSEndPoint" />

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="FaleConoscoWSBean" class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.FaleConoscoWSBean">
    </bean>

    <bean id="RoboFaleConoscoWSBean" class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.RoboFaleConoscoWSBean">
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="faleConoscoDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/FaleConoscoDS" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="icmsRJDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/ICMS_RJ_DS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="icmsSPDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/ICMS_SP_DS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="icmsRJ" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="icmsRJDS" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="icmsSP" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="icmsSPDS" />
    </bean>

    <util:map id="icmsPropertiesMap">
        <entry key="IP_RJ" value-ref="IP_ICMS_RJ" />
        <entry key="USUARIO_RJ" value-ref="USUARIO_ICMS_RJ" />
        <entry key="SENHA_RJ" value-ref="SENHA_ICMS_RJ" />
        <entry key="IP_SP" value-ref="IP_ICMS_SP" />
        <entry key="USUARIO_SP" value-ref="USUARIO_ICMS_SP" />
        <entry key="SENHA_SP" value-ref="SENHA_ICMS_SP" />
    </util:map>

    <!-- Lista de processadores de OS -->    
    <util:list id="processors">
        <bean class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.os.processor.ClienteProcessor" />
        <bean class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.os.processor.ServicoEquipamentoProcessor" />
        <bean class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.os.processor.SuspensaoProcessor" />
        <bean class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.os.processor.SaldoProcessor" />
        <bean class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.os.processor.DebitoAutomaticoProcessor" />
    </util:list>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.embratel.faleconosco">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="javax.jws.WebService" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <!-- <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="faleConoscoDS" /> 
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
                 <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="org.hibernate.type" value="true" />
                <entry key="org.hibernate.transaction" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaTemplate" class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.dao.JpaTemplateExt">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

      enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations 
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> --> 

    <bean id="ProtocoloWS" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxrpc.JaxRpcPortProxyFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
        <property name="serviceFactoryClass">
            <value>org.apache.axis.client.ServiceFactory</value>
        </property>
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" ref="PSACWSDocumentURL" />
        <property name="endpointAddress" ref="PSACWSEndPoint" />
        <property name="serviceName">
            <value>ProtocoloWSService</value>
        </property>
        <property name="namespaceUri">
            <value>http://webservices.protocolounico.embratel.com.br/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="portName">
            <value>ProtocoloWSPort</value>
        </property>
        <property name="portInterface">
            <value>br.com.embratel.protocolounico.webservices.ProtocoloWS</value>
        </property>   
        <property name="serviceInterface">
            <value>br.com.embratel.protocolounico.webservices.ProtocoloWS</value>
        </property>
        <property name="customPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry>
                    <key><value type="java.lang.String">axis.connection.timeout</value></key>
                    <value type="java.lang.Integer">300000</value>
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="LoggerAspect" class="br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.aop.LoggerAspect">
    </bean>

    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://ws.faleconosco.embratel.com.br/" id="faleconoscowsbean"
        implementor="#FaleConoscoWSBean" wsdlLocation="wsdl/faleconoscowsbean.wsdl" endpointName="tns:FaleConoscoWSPort"
        serviceName="tns:FaleConoscoWSService" address="/FaleConoscoWSPort">
        <jaxws:features>
            bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" /
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint> 

    <jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://ws.faleconosco.embratel.com.br/" id="robofaleconoscowsbean"
        implementor="#RoboFaleConoscoWSBean" wsdlLocation="wsdl/robofaleconoscowsbean.wsdl"
        endpointName="tns:RoboFaleConoscoWSPort" serviceName="tns:RoboFaleConoscoWSService" address="/RoboFaleConoscoWSPort">
        <jaxws:features>
            bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" /
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
</beans>
```

ERRORS

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'FaleConoscoWSBean': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.usuario.UsuarioService br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.FaleConoscoWSBean.usuarioService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usuarioServiceImpl': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.email.EnviarEmailService br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.usuario.UsuarioServiceImpl.enviarEmailService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'enviarEmailServiceImpl': Autowiring of fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.dao.JpaTemplateExt br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.service.BaseServiceImpl.jpaTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.dao.JpaTemplateExt] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [class br.com.embratel.faleconosco.ws.dao.JpaTemplateExt]: expected at least 1 matching bean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInstantiation(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at
```

Comment: Also show the spring configuration

Comment: There it is, if anything else is needed please let me know

Comment: You seem to be autowiring a bean of type `JpaTemplateExt` (which you have commented out) in your bean `BaseServiceImpl`

Comment: There are some class files with anotation @AutoWire, I don't know how what to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I Studied better Spring and re create the xml.

I removed this part of the code from the code above.
Creating the file from the begining.

```
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
             <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: For posterity, could you expand on your answer? As it is, this question isn't as useful to the wider community as it would be if your answer explained what in particular got you your answer. Edit this answer to include the working XML if applicable.